# SQL update query for balances using Access raises 'Operation must use an updateable query'

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following query (MS Access 2010) which I'm trying to use to update a table with a running balance:

```
UPDATE Accounts a SET a.CurrentBalance = 
(SELECT sum(iif(c.categoryid = 2,t.Amount * -1, t.Amount)) + 
        (select a1.openingbalance 
         from accounts a1 where a1.accountid = a.accountid) AS TotalAmount
FROM transactions t inner join (
     transactiontypes tt inner join 
     categories c on c.categoryid = tt.categoryid) 
     on t.transactiontypeid = tt.transactiontypeid);
```

The tables used are:

Answer (score 3):

A work around for the "Query must use an updateable query" is to use a temporary table and then update the final target data based on the aggregated data in the temporary table. In your case, as mwolfe suggests, you have an aggregate function in the inner select query. The workaround could provide a quick fix for this situation, as it has for me.

Ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328828

This article helped me understand the specifics of the situation and provided the work around: 
http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use aggregate functions (like `SUM`) in an update query.  See [Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) for a full list of conditions that will cause your query to be "non-updateable".

Answer (score 1):

The Access db engine includes support for domain functions (DMax, DSum, DLookup, etc.).  And domain functions can often allow you to circumvent non-updateable query problems.

Consider `DSum()` with these 3 rows of data in `MyTable`.

```
id MyNumber
 1        2
 2        3
 3        5
```

Then in the Immediate window, here are 2 sample `DSum()` expressions.

```
? DSum("MyNumber", "MyTable")
 10 

? DSum("IIf(id=1,MyNumber * -1, MyNumber)", "MyTable")
 6
```

I think you may be able to use something like that second expression as a replacement for the `sum(iif(c.categoryid = 2,t.Amount * -1, t.Amount)` part of your query.

And perhaps you can use a `DLookup()` expression to get your `TotalAmount` value.  Unfortunately I got frustrated trying to translate your current SQL to domain functions.  And I realize this isn't a complete solution, but hope it will point you to something useful.  If you edit your question to show us brief samples of the starting data and what you hope to achieve from your UPDATE statement based on that sample data, I would be willing to have another look at this.

Finally, consider whether you absolutely must store `CurrentBalance` in a table.  As a rule of thumb, avoid storing derived values.  Instead, use a SELECT query to compute the derived value when you need it.  That approach would guarantee `CurrentBalance` is always up-to-date whenever you retrieve it.  It would also spare you the effort to create a working UPDATE statement.